# Why pixels are copied backwards?

Tags: c, bitmap, buffer, pixel

I have a function that converts `.BMP` to a `.PPM`.
Since `.PPM` doesn't need padding at the end of each row of pixels, i have a loop that skips padding and writes each pixel to the `.PPM` file. However.. they are copied backwards. RGB->BGR. I don't know why, I thought `fwrite` writes all the bytes in sequence.

```
for(h = HEIGHT*((WIDTH*3) + WIDTH%4); h>=0; h -= (WIDTH*3) + WIDTH%4)
{
    fwrite(&BMPDATA[p->__Index][54 + h], 1, WIDTH*3, fp);
}
```

`BMPDATA` is a 2D buffer containing the `.BMP` file.

`54` is the offset of where the pixels starts from.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @chux I would use bitshift if it was pixel-by-pixel but it is row-by-row. This is a pretty good method for converting. What could i do without ruining its speed?

Comment: @chux are you willing to help me? This ER problem is ruining everything.

Comment: Copying to a new buffer? This will certainly reduce speed..

Comment: @chux I didn't understand that phrase `Get the function right first - then adjust for performance`

Comment: Yes, `fwrite` writes the bytes in the block verbatim, and that's your problem: PPM stores colour pixels in RGB order, but BMP uses BGR. You will have to loop through your pixels one by one and write the bytes in the order you want.

Comment: I just readed the `fwrite` function is actually simple. In fact, I am coding a reversal version of it.